# Python subprocess.run shell kwarg behavior

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

There has been a lot of questions regarding `shell` keyword argument. But I still don't really get it especially if we use the sequence argument instead of the string.

My understanding is that if `shell=False`, the `subprocess` module will run the executable in `args[0]` and pass the rest as arguments to the executable. But if we run it with `shell=True`, it will be ran as something like `"sh -c {}".format(format_escaping(args))`.

But why does this happen?

```py
# Ran in OSX

subprocess.run(["touch", "12; touch 34"]) # successfuly make the file '12; touch 34'

subprocess.run(["touch", "56; touch 78"], shell=True) # does not work:
# usage:
# touch [-A [-][[hh]mm]SS] [-acfhm] [-r file] [-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]] file ...
# CompletedProcess(args=['touch', '123; touch 456'], returncode=1)
```

What actually happen in `subprocess.run(["touch", "56; touch 79"], shell=True)`?

Answer (score 2):

I think with `shell=True` the supbrocess runs first only the first `parameter` which is `touch` therefore you become the help mesage from the command , try it like this instead:

```
subprocess.run("touch 56; touch 78", shell=True)
```

Comment: I see, then what happen to the rest of the arguments? e.g. when i run `subprocess.run(["touch", "touch"])`?

Comment: you should put all the parameters in one place

Comment: your first example will also give you `12; touch 34` so that considered as a paramete to first touch not a command like when you use shell=True

Comment: So is `subprocess.run(";".join(commands), shell=True)` is equivalent to `subprocess.run(commands, shell=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior when you pass in a list with `shell=True` is platform-dependent. On Unix-like platforms, Python simply passes in the first argument of the list.  On Windows, it happens to work, though it probably shouldn't.